# Vagrant command doesn't work without Sudo

Tags: terminal, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I have installed homestead with Vagrant in my MacOS. I have installed all with Virtual Box, but when i try to use vagrant command in my terminal for running Virtual Machine appear this error:

```
The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
be used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
```

I try with `sudo vagrant up` and it work but is not the best choice.
Anyone can help me?

There's a screenshot of the terminal Error:
[Terminal Error with command vagrant up and vagrant ssh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkXm3.png)

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2):

Try deleting .vagrant directory

```
rm -r .vagrant
```

I suspect you copied or moved project folder from one place to another.

Alternatively you need to update the creator_uid file in .vagrant/. Check out [this blog post](http://albertech.blogspot.com/2016/11/fix-vagrant-error-virtualbox-vm-was.html).